# PHP multi-dimentional array sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I would like to sort, that should be easy, except that I build my array in a strange manners (for different reasons) that make it hard to sort. Here is my array :

```
$arrayCEO =array(
'companyName' => array(0=>'name1', 1=>'name2'),
'link' => array (0=>'link1', 1=>'link2'),
'isin' => array (0=>'isin1', 1=>'isin2'),
'mktCap' => array (0=>'mktCap1', 1=>'mktCap2'),
'nbShares' => array (0=>'nbShares1', 1=>'nbShares2'),
'amount' => array (0=>'10', 1=>'20'));
```

Is that possible to sort by "amount" without breaking the order in the others arrays?
Do you recommend me to rewrite my code to build an array like this one :

```
$arrayCEO =array(
0 => array ('name' => 'name1', 'link' => 'link1', 'isin' => 'isin1', …),
1 => array ('name' => 'name2', 'link' => 'link2', 'isin' => 'isin2', …));
2 => ...
```

I know this one would be simple to sort but it's a lot of work to rewrite my piece of code.

Thanks,
Dorian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a lot more sense to rewrite your arrays to store in the more conventional format you described - (It's always better to organise things in decreasing magnitude 'Root > rows > fields' instead of 'Root > fields > rows')

If you didn't want to change you could probably use the usort function and roll your own sorting method, but it might be a bit of work to make it play nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will probably rewrite my arrays because, as you said, to found a way to sort mine would be as time consuming as rewriting.